# Error in building cmake project with custom source and include directories

Tags: c++, cmake

My project works fine, if all `.cpp` and `.h` files are in root directory.
But as soon as i use custom `src` and `include` directories for `.cpp` and `.h` respectively and change `CMakeLists.txt` files,  CMake build shows error.

Project Structure:

```
CMakeLists.txt
include
    mainwindow.h
src
    CMakeLists.txt
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
```

CMakkeLists.txt (root):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(Quick3D VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(src)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
```

CMakeLists.txt (src directory):

```
target_sources(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
)
```

Error :

```
CMake Warning (dev) at src/CMakeLists.txt:1 (target_sources):Policy CMP0076 is not set: target_sources() command converts relative paths
to absolute.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0076" for policy details.  Use
the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

A private source from a directory other than that of target "Quick3D" has a
relative path.CMake (target_sources)
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:1 (target_sources):Cannot find source file:

  main.cpp

Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .ixx .cppm
.ccm .cxxm .c++m .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90
.f95 .f03 .hip .ispc
```

Comment: Why do you want to list the same source files from two different CMakeLists files?

Comment: You declare a target in the root directory, all target sources are expected to be relative to the target.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I followed the https://github.com/ttroy50/cmake-examples/tree/master/01-basic/B-hello-headers and https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/basics/structure.html

Comment: @273K did not get your point, what should i need to change?

Comment: @273K actually it works, I just removed `add_executable()` line from root CMakeLists.txt file and add `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)` to src CMakeLists.txt file

Answer (score 0):

In CMake 3.7 `target_sources` command doesn't transform relative paths to absolute ones. All sources files attached with that command are interpreted relative to the directory where the **target is created**. That is, the invocation of

```cmake
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
)
```

from `src/CMakeLists.txt` is equivalent to adding those sources in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file with **unchanged** relative paths:

```cmake
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
# In the top-level CMakeLists.txt the following sources specification is wrong:
# it doesn't contain src/ subdirectory.
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
)
```

Things have been changed in CMake 3.13, when command [target_sources](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html) starts to transform relative paths to the absolute ones **immediately** when the command is called. And this is what CMake tells you with the warning about the policy [CMP0076](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0076.html)

```
CMake Warning (dev) at src/CMakeLists.txt:1 (target_sources):Policy CMP0076 is not set: target_sources() command converts relative paths
to absolute.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0076" for policy details.  Use
the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
```

The warning means that in the **current** CMake version the command `target_sources` transforms the relative paths. But since you specify 3.7 in the `cmake_minimum_required` call, CMake **preserves behavior for version 3.7**, where transformation is not performed.

So, the simple fix would be updating `cmake_minimum_required` specification to the VERSION 3.13 or upper:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
```